# Adjust SharePoint 2013 column width for multiple columns without SD

Tags: webpart-width

In SP 2013 I wish to add style code to change the width of columns. I have added code to wrap column titles, which works well; however, adding the subsequent statement to adjust column width fails to do anything. I am adding the following code to a Script Editor web part. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<style type= "text/css">
.ms-vh, .ms-vh2-nofilter, .ms-vh2-nograd, .ms-vh2, .ms-vb
{white-space: normal}

.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='<Column Name>']
{
  width:600px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the steps below:

1. Create a .txt file, then copy and paste the code below.
2. Upload the file to SharePoint library and copy the path url to the file.
3. Navigate to the list, click Edit Page under settings icon beside your account.
4. Add a web part > Categories: Media and Content > Parts: Content Editor
5. Edit content editor web part, type the url in step 2 into Content Link, click OK.
6. Under Page tab, click Stop Editing.

> $(document).ready(function()  { 
>   $("TH.ms-vh2:contains('Title')").css("width", "300px");  //I suppose
>   you would test on Title column with 300px. If you would like to modify
>   another column, replace “Title” with words in column name.   });

**Use this javascript code to change the width of the column in SharePoint List.**

**Note:-** You need to change the field names according to your list columns.

Comment: Thanks Hardik. Much appreciated. I am trying to avoid the usage of JavaScript to avoid page load delays. I know this can be done via CSS but think I have the formatting wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: You must use Content Editor Web Part for CSS. **As you have mentioned that** you had used Script Editor web part, It will not work with CSS in it. So please use Content Editor Web Part for CSS. If you want to use Script Editor web part than use above given script.

Comment: Hmm. As per my original post, I have successfully wrapped the list column headers using CSS in the Script Editor web part.

Comment: Did you find the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
table[summary="your webpart title"] .ms-viewheadertr th:nth-child(n) {
    width: 600px;
}
```

Needless to say, assign your destination column index at "n" of "nth-child(n)".
This code works on SharePoint Online, but it will also work on SP2013, I suppose.

Hope it will help!